# knockout.js selectedOptions is not updated

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js

I'm struggling with knockout.js selectedOptions binding.

I fill multiselect with items from observableArray A, choose some, store result in observableArray B. When item gets removed from array A, the B array is not updated.

Is this knockout issue or am I doing something wrong?

HTML code:

```
<h4>All items:</h4>
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove item</button>
</div>

<select multiple="multiple" data-bind="
    options: items,
    selectedOptions: selectedItems,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsCaption: 'Choose one or more...'
"></select>

<h4>Selected items:</h4>
<div data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">
    <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        { name: "Item 1", id: "1" },
        { name: "Item 2", id: "2" },
        { name: "Item 3", id: "3" }
    ]),
    selectedItems: ko.observableArray(),
    remove: function(item) {
        viewModel.items.remove(item);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3FYAe/

How to reproduce:

1. select one or more items in the multiselect field, they appear in the list below ("Selected items")
2. remove one of the selected items
3. the selectbox is updated

   4.

   - Expected: "Selected items" is updated
   - Actual: "Selected items" keeps deleted values

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

The trivial solution would be to remove the item from selectedItems array as well, i. e.

```
remove: function(item) {
    viewModel.items.remove(item);
    viewModel.selectedItems.remove(item);
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3FYAe/1/

However, I would like to find a nicer solution as I'm dealing with many more lists and many more dependencies; this is just a simplified example.

Comment: From the Knockout point of view `items` and `selectedItems` are two completly independent array which are happen to have the same elements sometimes. So it is your responsibility to keep the two arrays in sysnc if this is your requirement.

Comment: @nemesv I was kind of hoping that selectedOptions binding would prevent having non-existing values in it

Comment: You can create a custom "betterSelectedItems" binding by copying the code for the one that comes with KO.  In your version, subscribe to the `options` array and in your callback remove any items from the `selectedItems` array that are no longer in the `options` array.